# Find a Substring in T-SQL w/ varying position and length

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql

I have a series of strings like:

```
'...abcd=123-456-ABC,email=hello@world.com,...'
```

I would like to isolate the values of `abcd` & `email` and store them in their own variables.

I am using T-SQL.

Comment: What have you tried writing with `T-SQL`? Did you do a web-search to find `SUBSTRING` or `CHARINDEX`?

Comment: `abcd=(.+),email=(.+),` something like that?

Comment: Hi IMReal, is this still open? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: It would be very kind of you to tick the acceptance check below the best answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you crossed the 15 points border yourself you are asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, I was able to answer my own question as follows:

set string1 = SUBSTRING(TEXT, CHARINDEX('abcd=',TEXT)+5, CHARINDEX(',email',TEXT) - CHARINDEX('abcd=',TEXT)-5)

set string2 = SUBSTRING(TEXT, CHARINDEX('email=',TEXT)+6, CHARINDEX(',[next variable]',TEXT) - CHARINDEX('email=',TEXT)-6)

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
\w+=[^,]+
# look for word characters (min one)
# a =
# and anything not a comma
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/mX8hW7/1).

Answer (score 1):

With T-SQL you might try this

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT, YourString NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,N'abcd=123-456-ABC,email=hello@world.com')
,(2,N'abcd=SomeOther,email=test@world.com')
,(3,N'abcd=OneMore,other=123,AnOneMore=abc');

WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT YourString AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),N',',N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML) AS InParts
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT ID
      ,LEFT(The.Part,CHARINDEX('=',The.Part)-1) AS Caption
      ,SUBSTRING(The.Part,CHARINDEX('=',The.Part)+1,1000) AS Value
FROM Splitted
CROSS APPLY Splitted.InParts.nodes('/x') AS A(B)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT B.value('.','nvarchar(max)')) AS The(Part)
```

The result

```
ID  Caption     Value
1   abcd        123-456-ABC
1   email       hello@world.com
2   abcd        SomeOther
2   email       test@world.com
3   abcd        OneMore
3   other       123
3   AnOneMore   abc
```